# While loops in programming C#

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to create a program which asks for integers off a user and adds them up within a while loop, and then when a negative number is entered, the loop ends, But for some reason I can't find a way to add up the number the user adds to the total, it just displays both the total which is initially 0 next to the subtotal (amount user enters)

```
int iNumber =0;
int iTotal = 0;
int iSubTotal = 0;

//Prompt user to enter two values
Console.WriteLine("Enter value you want to add to total value or a negative number to end the loop");

while (iNumber >= 0)
{
    iSubTotal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine("The Total is now " + iSubTotal + iTotal);

    if (iNumber < 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You have not passed the loop");
        Console.WriteLine("The Total is now " + iTotal);
    }

    //Prevent program from closing
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: No where you're accumulating the result

Comment: Try adding the line `iTotal = iTotal + iNumber;`

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("The Total is now " + iSubTotal + iTotal);` this is converting them to strings, and concatenating them together

Comment: You are not assigning the additionto a variable here "iSubTotal + iTotal"

Comment: @jonhopkins I think you mean `iTotal = iTotal + iSubTotal;` I *think* iNumber is some sort of counter counting up from a engative number, looks like we can't see all of the loop

Comment: I assume some of the loop is missing, since you say it ends, yet there is nothing shown that would change iNumber,

Comment: iNumber has never been reassigned in the given code snippets.

Comment: `while (true) if (false) Console.WriteLine("This is your first clue...");`

Comment: @AaronLS, you're right, it's most likely `iSubTotal`. There's a bunch of variables that are never assigned to, so I just picked ones that seemed to make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're never modifying `iSubTotal` or `iTotal` in the code.  So their values are never changing.

Somewhere in the loop you'd likely want to modify the value(s):

```
// ...
iSubTotal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("The Total is now " + iSubTotal + iTotal);
iTotal += iNumber;
// ...
```

**Edit:** Based on your comment below, it sounds like you need to handle input a little more robustly.  `Convert.ToInt32()` will fail if the string isn't convertible into an integer.  You can make this a little more robust with something like this:

```
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out iSubTotal))
{
    // Parsing to an integer succeeded, iSubTotal now contains the new value
}
else
{
    // Parsing to an integer failed, respond to the user
}
```

Comment: Not somewhere, after he displays it would be ideal, otherwise it would display incorrect total.

Comment: Tried this and it display "input string was not in correct format" for the "iSubTotal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());"

Comment: any ideas how to fix?

Comment: @Alex: That's exactly a line of code copied from your original code.  If that's failing it's a different problem entirely.  But to fix it, you want to use `int.TryParse()` instead of `Convert.ToInt32()`.  I'll update the answer in a moment...

Comment: I think this is the fix, I'll just have to try overcome the other problem I've got, thanks!

Comment: Ahh okay, just seen your reply, I'll give that a go, thanks david for the help

Comment: @Alex: The answer has now been updated with an example.  Basically always try to use `TryParse()` anywhere that you don't want an error to occur if parsing fails.  It fails into a boolean value instead of into an exception.

Comment: It seems to work now, but only for double integers? Like 10, 22, 45 etc. Doesn't seem to work for numbers like 1, 4, 2 etc. Not quite sure why this is, but you've help me alot, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigning the additionto a variable here "iSubTotal + iTotal"

```
iTotal += iSubTotal;
Console.WriteLine("The Total is now " + iTotal);
```

Instead of these two lines

```
iSubTotal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("The Total is now " + iSubTotal + iTotal);
```

Comment: +1 He probably still needs the readline as I assume it's user input for the subtotal, but yeh this is the answer.

Comment: Hmm yeah, like aaron said, I need a way for the user to input the subtotal, I've replaced the code with this, and it just displays straight away that the total is 0 ?

Comment: @Alex Just put `iSubTotal = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());` before the other two lines

Answer (score 0):

thats because

```
 Console.WriteLine("The Total is now " + iSubTotal + iTotal);
```

is incorrect. If you are adding 2 numbers together, you need to store the answer somewhere, you are not when using Console.Write the + symbol is used to concatenate not add.

Answer (score 0):

You never change iNumber or iTotal. I think something like this is more what you want at the top.

```
while (iNumber >= 0)
    {
        iNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        iTotal += iNumber;
        Console.WriteLine("The Total is now " + iSubTotal + iTotal);
...
```

Answer (score -2):

iSubTotal + iTotal

should be

(iSubTotal + iTotal)

otherwise it is read as a string.

Comment: It's still being converted to a string, all this does is specify the order of operations for the operators (which was already in this order).